# jquery.transit does not animate during scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, css-transitions

I am producing an iPad app using phonegap, and in that connection I've taken a liking to [jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) which easily helps me with css3 animations.

However, I encountered an obstacle. I am making an online list that will add new users as they log in. There is no problem adding DOM elements while scrolling the page, however, when adding the css3 animation to "unfold" the element, the animation only works when not scrolling. As a result elements with height: 0; will not produce the desired height:56px; when running the animation on it.

--- EDIT ---

It appears this problem is related to scrolling in other divs than the one running the animations. If I scroll the div containing the friendList (which is fixed with overflow auto) it works fine while scrolling. It's only a problem when scrolling the actual page and iOS native scrolling kicks in.

--- EDIT ---

The code looks as follow:

```
<ul class="friendList">
  <li class="friendElement">
     <div class="friendWrapper">
     (content here)
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

where

```
.friendWrapper.entering{
   height:0;
}
```

and on friend login:

```
var $friendTemplate = (... appropriate template goes here ...);

function friendLogsOn(){
   var $newFriend = $friendTemplate.clone(),
   $friendList = $(".friendList"),
   nmbElements = $friendList.children().length,
   rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*nmbElements);
   $newFriend.find(".friendWrapper").addClass("entering");
   $newFriend.insertAfter($friendList.children().eq(rand));
   $newFriend.find(".friendWrapper").transition({ height: '56px' },function(){
      $(this).removeClass("entering");
   });
}
```

I haven't been able to make jquery.transition activate animations while the user is scrolling, does anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: yeah seeing the same on Iphone with IOS5. Really annoying. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I did however notice that this is even more outspoken on .animate() using jquery's native. When using animate, you can halt animations mid-way by scrolling and they won't continue once the scrolling event is done, where transit halts animations but continues after scrolling is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to animate while doing regular page scrolling, since iOS renders the whole page when scrolling starts.

This is done to improve performance. Other smartphones and tables also do the same thing.

You could use a plugin like iScroll4 to achieve the result. iScroll doesn't do regular scrolling, but listens to mouse/touch events, and then moves elements to simulate scrolling.
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

If you want to test if animation is halted on scroll i've made a simple jsfiddle you can try out. (on iPad, iPhone, android devices etc.)
http://jsfiddle.net/3ntKM/4/embedded/result/

```
<style>
    #square {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: auto;
        background: red;
        -webkit-animation: rotate 4s infinite linear;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
</style>
<div id="square"></div>
```